# how to create group of consistent records

Tags: mysql, sql

i have following data ,there i want to get record set of consistent data that are in sequence (asc or desc) on the basis of **angle** column

```
id      angle   force
3146    0.4     -0.04
3147    1.87    -0.05
3148    3.1     -0.06
3149    4.88    -0.01
3150    6.43    0
3151    7.92    0.01
3152    9.61    0.01
3153    11.03   0.01
3154    12.51   0.02
3155    13.95   0.02
3156    15.53   0.03
3157    16.88   0.04
3158    18.38   0.07
3159    19.78   0.1
3160    21.15   0.13
3161    22.28   0.11
3162    24.12   0.1
3163    25.85   0.1
3164    27.34   0.1
3165    29.02   0.11
3166    30.51   0.11
3167    31.82   0.12
3168    33.08   0.12
3169    34.43   0.12
3170    35.91   0.12
3171    37.13   0.12
3172    38.41   0.13
3173    39.94   0.13
3174    41.24   0.14
3175    42.97   0.14
3176    44.53   0.14
3177    46.17   0.15
3178    47.86   0.15
3179    49.32   0.15
3180    50.87   0.16
3181    52.09   0.15
3182    53.35   0.15
3183    54.79   0.15
3184    56.16   0.14
3185    57.35   0.15
3186    58.79   0.15
3187    60.21   0.14
3188    61.47   0.14
3189    63.2    0.15
3190    64.67   0.15
3191    66.28   0.16
3192    67.99   0.17
3193    69.53   0.17
3194    71.15   0.18
3195    72.67   0.19
3196    75.04   0.06
3197    76.57   0.06
3198    78.17   0.07
3199    79.74   0.08
3200    81.31   0.1
3201    82.71   0.12
3202    84.33   0.13
3203    85.68   0.15
3204    87.28   0.16
3205    88.58   0.22
3206    90.04   0.25
3207    91.58   0.26
3208    93.13   0.24
3209    94.64   0.23
3210    96.55   0.21
3211    98.17   0.19
3212    99.7    0.18
3213    101.21  0.18
3214    102.65  0.22
3215    103.93  0.24
3216    105.01  0.28
3217    103.75  0.27
3218    102.19  0.25
3219    100.64  0.19
3220    99.09   0.06
3221    97.74   0.03
3222    96.39   -0.03
3223    95.04   -0.05
3224    93.67   -0.02
3225    92.39   0
3226    91.01   0.01
3227    89.59   0.01
3228    88.07   0.01
3229    86.62   0
3230    85.05   -0.04
3231    83.48   -0.07
3232    81.88   -0.1
3233    80.06   -0.08
3234    78.48   -0.07
3235    76.91   -0.07
3236    74.74   -0.03
3237    73.15   -0.03
3238    71.66   -0.04
3239    69.66   -0.01
3240    67.88   -0.03
3241    66.2    -0.07
3242    64.62   -0.1
3243    63.09   -0.13
3244    61.67   -0.16
3245    60.32   -0.2
3246    58.57   -0.22
3247    57.02   -0.26
3248    55.4    -0.29
3249    53.69   -0.31
3250    52.22   -0.32
3251    50.47   -0.32
3252    48.98   -0.3
3253    47.5    -0.29
3254    45.95   -0.28
3255    44.48   -0.28
3256    43.06   -0.28
3257    41.45   -0.29
3258    40.23   -0.3
3259    38.77   -0.31
3260    37.04   -0.32
3261    35.51   -0.35
3262    36.83   -0.34
3263    38.25   -0.32
3264    39.65   -0.24
3265    40.97   -0.22
3266    42.46   -0.21
3267    44.21   -0.19
3268    45.92   -0.17
3269    47.61   -0.15
3270    49.34   -0.15
3271    50.83   -0.13
3272    52.2    -0.11
3273    53.75   -0.07
3274    54.99   -0.06
3275    56.41   -0.05
3276    57.89   -0.05
3277    59.18   -0.04
3278    60.55   -0.03
3279    62.26   -0.02
3280    63.77   -0.01
3281    65.23   0
3282    67.18   0
3283    68.94   0
3284    70.63   0.02
3285    72.34   0.03
3286    73.96   0.05
3287    75.8    0.05
3288    77.33   0.05
3289    78.89   0.1
3290    80.5    0.14
3291    81.94   0.16
3292    83.38   0.2
3293    84.92   0.28
3294    86.49   0.3
3295    87.88   0.38
3296    89.35   0.42
3297    90.76   0.44
3298    92.29   0.47
3299    93.69   0.58
3300    95.53   0.64
3301    97.06   0.53
3302    98.69   0.46
3303    100.48  0.46
3304    101.92  0.48
3305    103.39  0.49
3306    104.69  0.51
3307    106.18  0.53
3308    107.03  0.58
3309    105.88  0.58
3310    104.24  0.55
3311    102.69  0.47
3312    101.25  0.19
3313    100.03  0.16
3314    98.46   0.17
3315    97.2    0.13
3316    95.99   0.1
3317    94.61   0.08
3318    93.26   0.07
3319    92.02   0.1
3320    90.4    0.12
3321    88.97   0.11
3322    87.19   0.11
3323    85.39   0.1
3324    83.79   0.1
3325    82.03   0.1
3326    80.37   0.11
3327    78.84   0.11
3328    77.49   0.08
3329    76.01   0.03
3330    74.99   0
3331    73.8    0
3332    72.09   -0.01
3333    70.38   -0.03
3334    68.65   -0.04
3335    66.94   -0.07
3336    65.54   -0.1
3337    63.83   -0.13
3338    62.55   -0.16
3339    60.71   -0.17
3340    59.06   -0.21
3341    57.49   -0.21
3342    55.64   -0.19
3343    54.02   -0.14
3344    52.63   -0.12
3345    51.23   -0.09
3346    49.55   -0.09
3347    48.19   -0.09
3348    46.6    -0.1
3349    45.22   -0.11
3350    43.56   -0.11
3351    42.23   -0.11
3352    40.54   -0.11
3353    39.04   -0.11
3354    37.39   -0.11
3355    35.68   -0.11
3356    34.13   -0.11
3357    32.62   -0.12
3358    31.19   -0.11
3359    29.74   -0.11
3360    28.31   -0.11
3361    27.14   -0.11
3362    25.67   -0.11
3363    24.35   -0.12
3364    23.06   -0.12
3365    21.53   -0.12
3366    20.14   -0.12
3367    18.47   -0.12
3368    17.01   -0.13
3369    15.25   -0.12
3370    13.9    -0.13
3371    12.17   -0.13
3372    10.76   -0.13
3373    9.32    -0.13
3374    8.03    -0.13
3375    6.59    -0.13
3376    5.2 -0.13
3377    3.83    -0.13
3378    2.14    -0.13
3379    -0.02   -0.08
3380    1.01    -0.08
3381    2   -0.07
3382    2.97    -0.05
3383    4.03    -0.01
3384    4.97    0.01
3385    6.07    0.01
3386    6.97    0.01
3387    8.15    0.02
3388    9.14    0.02
3389    10.35   0.02
3390    11.29   0.03
3391    12.42   0.03
3392    13.27   0.03
3393    14.6    0.04
3394    15.66   0.05
3395    16.69   0.07
3396    18.23   0.09
3397    19.19   0.15
3398    20.16   0.18
3399    21.19   0.2
3400    22.16   0.2
3401    23.24   0.18
3402    24.23   0.17
3403    25.27   0.15
3404    26.28   0.14
3405    27.22   0.13
3406    28.4    0.11
3407    29.41   0.1
3408    30.76   0.11
3409    31.81   0.1
3410    32.83   0.11
3411    33.8    0.11
3412    34.85   0.11
3413    35.82   0.11
3414    36.99   0.11
3415    37.91   0.11
3416    38.95   0.11
3417    40.05   0.12
3418    40.91   0.12
3419    42.03   0.12
3420    42.89   0.12
3421    44.03   0.12
3422    44.91   0.13
3423    46.04   0.13
3424    47  0.14
3425    48.04   0.13
3426    48.94   0.13
3427    49.95   0.13
3428    50.96   0.13
3429    51.95   0.13
3430    52.96   0.13
3431    53.95   0.13
3432    55.03   0.13
3433    56.18   0.14
3434    58.45   0.14
3435    59.31   0.14
3436    60.3    0.13
3437    61.33   0.14
3438    62.37   0.14
3439    63.29   0.14
3440    64.39   0.15
3441    65.38   0.15
3442    66.42   0.15
3443    67.39   0.15
3444    68.53   0.15
3445    69.5    0.15
3446    70.58   0.15
3447    71.46   0.15
3448    72.54   0.16
3449    73.46   0.17
3450    75.02   0.06
3451    75.8    0.06
3452    76.97   0.06
3453    77.94   0.07
3454    78.95   0.07
3455    80.17   0.11
3456    81.47   0.14
3457    82.37   0.1
3458    83.38   0.08
3459    84.65   0.08
3460    85.59   0.08
3461    86.76   0.09
3462    87.7    0.12
3463    88.7    0.12
3464    89.98   0.14
3465    91.15   0.15
3466    92.23   0.17
3467    93.22   0.19
3468    94.23   0.22
3469    95.27   0.24
3470    96.17   0.24
3471    97.4    0.23
3472    98.37   0.23
3473    99.52   0.22
3474    100.48  0.21
3475    101.65  0.2
3476    102.73  0.2
3477    103.68  0.19
3478    104.85  0.2
3479    103.66  0.2
3480    102.71  0.2
3481    101.7   0.19
3482    100.73  0.19
3483    99.7    0.18
3484    98.73   0.12
3485    97.04   0.06
3486    95.67   0.03
3487    94.05   0.02
3488    92.75   0.02
3489    91.3    0.02
3490    89.87   0.02
3491    88.2    -0.01
3492    86.76   -0.02
3493    85.39   -0.04
3494    83.88   -0.04
3495    82.31   -0.04
3496    80.82   -0.03
3497    79.51   -0.02
3498    77.85    0
3499    76.61    0
3500    74.79   -0.07
3501    73.24   -0.07
3502    71.44   -0.09
3503    69.82   -0.14
3504    68.44   -0.16
3505    66.76   -0.18
3506    65.43   -0.23
3507    63.88   -0.26
3508    62.41   -0.28
3509    60.61   -0.32
3510    59.22   -0.31
3511    57.58   -0.31
3512    55.84   -0.29
3513    54.09   -0.28
3514    52.24   -0.28
3515    50.47   -0.28
3516    48.44   -0.29
3517    46.89   -0.29
3518    45.36   -0.3
3519    43.74   -0.32
3520    42.01   -0.32
3521    40.27   -0.34
3522    38.57   -0.37
3523    36.81   -0.36
3524    34.96   -0.4
3525    36.32   -0.39
3526    37.78   -0.39
3527    39.44   -0.3
3528    40.93   -0.26
3529    42.82   -0.23
3530    44.41   -0.2
3531    45.86   -0.19
3532    47.66   -0.18
3533    49.14   -0.18
3534    50.76   -0.14
3535    51.98   -0.11
3536    53.55   -0.1
3537    55.03   -0.1
3538    56.47   -0.09
3539    58      -0.08
3540    59.65   -0.07
3541    61.07   -0.06
3542    62.64   -0.05
3543    63.99   -0.05
3544    65.81   -0.03
3545    67.07   -0.03
3546    68.42   -0.02
3547    69.89   -0.01
3548    71.15   -0.01
3549    72.79   -0.01
3550    73.55   -0.01
3551    75.02   -0.01
3552    76.23   -0.01
3553    78.1    -0.01
3554    79.6    0
3555    81.23   0.03
3556    82.93   0.09
3557    84.65   0.11
3558    86.38   0.13
3559    88.25   0.16
3560    89.87   0.22
3561    91.64   0.29
3562    93.37   0.37
3563    94.52   0.41
3564    95.69   0.44
3565    97.38   0.44
3566    98.75   0.44
3567    100.46  0.43
3568    101.84  0.43
3569    103.55  0.43
3570    104.85  0.44
3571    107.01  0.46
3572    105.61  0.46
3573    104.24  0.46
3574    102.8   0.41
3575    101.21  0.3
3576    99.54   0.21
3577    98.26   0.19
3578    96.68   0.15
3579    95.31   0.14
3580    93.92   0.13
3581    92.23   0.12
3582    90.45   0.11
3583    89.14   0.11
3584    87.57   0.13
3585    86.13   0.13
3586    84.56   0.12
3587    83.18   0.1
3588    81.52   0.03
3589    79.99   0.02
3590    78.16   0
3591    76.32   -0.02
3592    74.95   -0.06
3593    73.4    -0.06
3594    71.93   -0.06
3595    70.15   -0.1
3596    68.58   -0.14
3597    66.82   -0.15
3598    65      -0.18
3599    63.14   -0.17
3600    61.4    -0.14
3601    59.58   -0.11
3602    57.8    -0.09
3603    56.16   -0.09
3604    54.49   -0.08
3605    52.78   -0.07
3606    51.05   -0.08
3607    49.43   -0.08
3608    47.66   -0.08
3609    45.94   -0.08
3610    44.37   -0.08
3611    42.79   -0.08
3612    41.38   -0.09
3613    39.71   -0.1
3614    38.25   -0.1
3615    36.67   -0.1
3616    35.03   -0.1
3617    33.43   -0.11
3618    31.97   -0.11
3619    30.29   -0.11
3620    28.69   -0.12
3621    27.27   -0.12
3622    25.52   -0.11
3623    24.07   -0.12
3624    22.48   -0.11
3625    20.99   -0.11
3626    19.31   -0.11
3627    18      -0.11
3628    16.31   -0.11
3629    14.78   -0.11
3630    13.39   -0.11
3631    12.1    -0.11
3632    10.55   -0.12
3633    9.13    -0.12
3634    7.87    -0.12
3635    6.32    -0.12
3636    4.36    -0.11
3637    2.9     -0.09
3638    1.26    -0.06
```

group 1st of data sequence (Ascending)

```
    id     angle    torque 
    3146    0.4     -0.04
    3147    1.87    -0.05
    3148    3.1     -0.06
    3149    4.88    -0.01
    3150    6.43    0
    3151    7.92    0.01
    3152    9.61    0.01
    3153    11.03   0.01
    3154    12.51   0.02
    3155    13.95   0.02
    3156    15.53   0.03
    3157    16.88   0.04
    3158    18.38   0.07
    3159    19.78   0.1
    3160    21.15   0.13
    3161    22.28   0.11
    3162    24.12   0.1
    3163    25.85   0.1
    3164    27.34   0.1
    3165    29.02   0.11
    3166    30.51   0.11
    3167    31.82   0.12
    3168    33.08   0.12
    3169    34.43   0.12
    3170    35.91   0.12
    3171    37.13   0.12
    3172    38.41   0.13
    3173    39.94   0.13
    3174    41.24   0.14
    3175    42.97   0.14
    3176    44.53   0.14
    3177    46.17   0.15
    3178    47.86   0.15
    3179    49.32   0.15
    3180    50.87   0.16
    3181    52.09   0.15
    3182    53.35   0.15
    3183    54.79   0.15
    3184    56.16   0.14
    3185    57.35   0.15
    3186    58.79   0.15
    3187    60.21   0.14
    3188    61.47   0.14
    3189    63.2    0.15
    3190    64.67   0.15
    3191    66.28   0.16
    3192    67.99   0.17
    3193    69.53   0.17
    3194    71.15   0.18
    3195    72.67   0.19
    3196    75.04   0.06
    3197    76.57   0.06
    3198    78.17   0.07
    3199    79.74   0.08
    3200    81.31   0.1
    3201    82.71   0.12
    3202    84.33   0.13
    3203    85.68   0.15
    3204    87.28   0.16
    3205    88.58   0.22
    3206    90.04   0.25
    3207    91.58   0.26
    3208    93.13   0.24
    3209    94.64   0.23
    3210    96.55   0.21
    3211    98.17   0.19
    3212    99.7    0.18
    3213    101.21  0.18
    3214    102.65  0.22
    3215    103.93  0.24
    3216    105.01  0.28
    3217    103.75  0.27
    3218    102.19  0.25
    3219    100.64  0.19
```

2nd group set of data sequence (descending)

```
    3220    99.09   0.06
    3221    97.74   0.03
    3222    96.39   -0.03
    3223    95.04   -0.05
    3224    93.67   -0.02
    3225    92.39   0
    3226    91.01   0.01
    3227    89.59   0.01
    3228    88.07   0.01
    3229    86.62   0
    3230    85.05   -0.04
    3231    83.48   -0.07
    3232    81.88   -0.1
    3233    80.06   -0.08
    3234    78.48   -0.07
    3235    76.91   -0.07
    3236    74.74   -0.03
    3237    73.15   -0.03
    3238    71.66   -0.04
    3239    69.66   -0.01
    3240    67.88   -0.03
    3241    66.2    -0.07
    3242    64.62   -0.1
    3243    63.09   -0.13
    3244    61.67   -0.16
    3245    60.32   -0.2
    3246    58.57   -0.22
    3247    57.02   -0.26
    3248    55.4    -0.29
    3249    53.69   -0.31
    3250    52.22   -0.32
    3251    50.47   -0.32
    3252    48.98   -0.3
    3253    47.5    -0.29
    3254    45.95   -0.28
    3255    44.48   -0.28
    3256    43.06   -0.28
    3257    41.45   -0.29
    3258    40.23   -0.3
    3259    38.77   -0.31
    3260    37.04   -0.32
    3261    35.51   -0.35
    3262    36.83   -0.34
```

remaining else data will become same record set as given sequence

i tried this using self join but it didn't work

your help is appreciable

Comment: You need both ordering in same resultset?

Comment: Maybe you could simplify the problem.

Comment: The example does not make sense. The ASC set is descending at the end and the DESC set does not start from the highest/next to highest value

Comment: @Viki888 i want both data set in differenet queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left this here just for fun, you might want to take a look on my other solution.

---

1st ASC section

```
select  *
from    mytable as t1
where   not exists
        (
            select      null  
            from        mytable as t2
            where       t2.id < t1.id
                    and exists
                        (
                            select      null
                            from        mytable t3
                            where       t3.id    < t2.id
                                    and t3.angle > t2.angle
                        )
        )
```

---

The picture describe a row (t1) that we are **not** going to choose  .

The main Idea -
Take a row (t1) only if it has no preceding row (t2) that has a preceding row (t3) with greater angle value (greater than t2)

[image]

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal, I want to give an alternative solution, so get back to it later

Comment: even i have to device_id & cycle check in where condition for this result set......how can i apply & on which part ...any idea plz

Comment: can we do it using for loop...if yes then how

Comment: No need to. Take a look on my other solution.

Answer (score 1):

This adds sequential numbers to each section.
You can use it as a sub-query and filter only the sections you want.
The extreme points (is that the correct English term?) are always added to the later section if you want it otherwise just change `t.id <= m.id` to `t.id < m.id`

---

The main idea here is to first find the extreme point by comparing each row to the row preceding it and the row following it and than count for each row, how many extreme point  are preceding it.

```
select      m.*

          ,(select      count(*)

            from                    mytable as t

                        join        mytable as t_before

                        on          t_before.id = t.id - 1

                        join        mytable as t_after

                        on          t_after.id = t.id + 1

            where       (   t.angle > greatest (t_before.angle,t_after.angle)
                        or  t.angle < least    (t_before.angle,t_after.angle)       
                        )

                    and t.id <= m.id

            ) + 1 as section_seq

from        mytable m   
;
```

P.s.
If ID cannot be trusted to be sequential (no gaps), then you'll have to use the following code.
Don't panic, the sub-queries are duplicated and they are only intended to generate a row number for the set.

```
select      m.*

          ,(select      count(*)

            from                   (select      t1.id,t1.angle,t1.force,count(*) as n

                                    from                    mytable t1

                                                left join   mytable t2

                                                on          t2.id <=
                                                            t1.id

                                    group by    t1.id,t1.angle,t1.force     
                                    ) as t

                        join       (select      t1.id,t1.angle,t1.force,count(*) as n

                                    from                    mytable t1

                                                left join   mytable t2

                                                on          t2.id <=
                                                            t1.id

                                    group by    t1.id,t1.angle,t1.force     
                                    ) as t_before

                        on          t_before.id = t.id - 1

                        join       (select      t1.id,t1.angle,t1.force,count(*) as n

                                    from                    mytable t1

                                                left join   mytable t2

                                                on          t2.id <=
                                                            t1.id

                                    group by    t1.id,t1.angle,t1.force     
                                    ) as t_after

                        on          t_after.id = t.id + 1

            where       (   t.angle > greatest (t_before.angle,t_after.angle)
                        or  t.angle < least    (t_before.angle,t_after.angle)       
                        )

                    and t.id <= m.id

            ) + 1 as section_seq            

from        mytable m   
;
```

---

```
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| id   | angle  | force | section_seq |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3146 | 0.4    | -0.04 | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3147 | 1.87   | -0.05 | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3148 | 3.1    | -0.06 | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3149 | 4.88   | -0.01 | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3150 | 6.43   | 0.0   | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3151 | 7.92   | 0.01  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3152 | 9.61   | 0.01  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3153 | 11.03  | 0.01  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3154 | 12.51  | 0.02  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3155 | 13.95  | 0.02  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3156 | 15.53  | 0.03  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3157 | 16.88  | 0.04  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3158 | 18.38  | 0.07  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3159 | 19.78  | 0.1   | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3160 | 21.15  | 0.13  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3161 | 22.28  | 0.11  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3162 | 24.12  | 0.1   | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3163 | 25.85  | 0.1   | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3164 | 27.34  | 0.1   | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3165 | 29.02  | 0.11  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3166 | 30.51  | 0.11  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3167 | 31.82  | 0.12  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3168 | 33.08  | 0.12  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3169 | 34.43  | 0.12  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3170 | 35.91  | 0.12  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3171 | 37.13  | 0.12  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3172 | 38.41  | 0.13  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3173 | 39.94  | 0.13  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3174 | 41.24  | 0.14  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3175 | 42.97  | 0.14  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3176 | 44.53  | 0.14  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3177 | 46.17  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3178 | 47.86  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3179 | 49.32  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3180 | 50.87  | 0.16  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3181 | 52.09  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3182 | 53.35  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3183 | 54.79  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3184 | 56.16  | 0.14  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3185 | 57.35  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3186 | 58.79  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3187 | 60.21  | 0.14  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3188 | 61.47  | 0.14  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3189 | 63.2   | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3190 | 64.67  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3191 | 66.28  | 0.16  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3192 | 67.99  | 0.17  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3193 | 69.53  | 0.17  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3194 | 71.15  | 0.18  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3195 | 72.67  | 0.19  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3196 | 75.04  | 0.06  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3197 | 76.57  | 0.06  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3198 | 78.17  | 0.07  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3199 | 79.74  | 0.08  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3200 | 81.31  | 0.1   | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3201 | 82.71  | 0.12  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3202 | 84.33  | 0.13  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3203 | 85.68  | 0.15  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3204 | 87.28  | 0.16  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3205 | 88.58  | 0.22  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3206 | 90.04  | 0.25  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3207 | 91.58  | 0.26  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3208 | 93.13  | 0.24  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3209 | 94.64  | 0.23  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3210 | 96.55  | 0.21  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3211 | 98.17  | 0.19  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3212 | 99.7   | 0.18  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3213 | 101.21 | 0.18  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3214 | 102.65 | 0.22  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3215 | 103.93 | 0.24  | 1           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3216 | 105.01 | 0.28  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3217 | 103.75 | 0.27  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3218 | 102.19 | 0.25  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3219 | 100.64 | 0.19  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3220 | 99.09  | 0.06  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3221 | 97.74  | 0.03  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3222 | 96.39  | -0.03 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3223 | 95.04  | -0.05 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3224 | 93.67  | -0.02 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3225 | 92.39  | 0.0   | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3226 | 91.01  | 0.01  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3227 | 89.59  | 0.01  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3228 | 88.07  | 0.01  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3229 | 86.62  | 0.0   | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3230 | 85.05  | -0.04 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3231 | 83.48  | -0.07 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3232 | 81.88  | -0.1  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3233 | 80.06  | -0.08 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3234 | 78.48  | -0.07 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3235 | 76.91  | -0.07 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3236 | 74.74  | -0.03 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3237 | 73.15  | -0.03 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3238 | 71.66  | -0.04 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3239 | 69.66  | -0.01 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3240 | 67.88  | -0.03 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3241 | 66.2   | -0.07 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3242 | 64.62  | -0.1  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3243 | 63.09  | -0.13 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3244 | 61.67  | -0.16 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3245 | 60.32  | -0.2  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3246 | 58.57  | -0.22 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3247 | 57.02  | -0.26 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3248 | 55.4   | -0.29 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3249 | 53.69  | -0.31 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3250 | 52.22  | -0.32 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3251 | 50.47  | -0.32 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3252 | 48.98  | -0.3  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3253 | 47.5   | -0.29 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3254 | 45.95  | -0.28 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3255 | 44.48  | -0.28 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3256 | 43.06  | -0.28 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3257 | 41.45  | -0.29 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3258 | 40.23  | -0.3  | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3259 | 38.77  | -0.31 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3260 | 37.04  | -0.32 | 2           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3261 | 35.51  | -0.35 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3262 | 36.83  | -0.34 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3263 | 38.25  | -0.32 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3264 | 39.65  | -0.24 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3265 | 40.97  | -0.22 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3266 | 42.46  | -0.21 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3267 | 44.21  | -0.19 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3268 | 45.92  | -0.17 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3269 | 47.61  | -0.15 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3270 | 49.34  | -0.15 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3271 | 50.83  | -0.13 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3272 | 52.2   | -0.11 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3273 | 53.75  | -0.07 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3274 | 54.99  | -0.06 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3275 | 56.41  | -0.05 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3276 | 57.89  | -0.05 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3277 | 59.18  | -0.04 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3278 | 60.55  | -0.03 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3279 | 62.26  | -0.02 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3280 | 63.77  | -0.01 | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3281 | 65.23  | 0.0   | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3282 | 67.18  | 0.0   | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3283 | 68.94  | 0.0   | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3284 | 70.63  | 0.02  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3285 | 72.34  | 0.03  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3286 | 73.96  | 0.05  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3287 | 75.8   | 0.05  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3288 | 77.33  | 0.05  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3289 | 78.89  | 0.1   | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3290 | 80.5   | 0.14  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3291 | 81.94  | 0.16  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3292 | 83.38  | 0.2   | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3293 | 84.92  | 0.28  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3294 | 86.49  | 0.3   | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3295 | 87.88  | 0.38  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3296 | 89.35  | 0.42  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3297 | 90.76  | 0.44  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3298 | 92.29  | 0.47  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3299 | 93.69  | 0.58  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3300 | 95.53  | 0.64  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3301 | 97.06  | 0.53  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3302 | 98.69  | 0.46  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3303 | 100.48 | 0.46  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3304 | 101.92 | 0.48  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3305 | 103.39 | 0.49  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3306 | 104.69 | 0.51  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3307 | 106.18 | 0.53  | 3           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3308 | 107.03 | 0.58  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3309 | 105.88 | 0.58  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3310 | 104.24 | 0.55  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3311 | 102.69 | 0.47  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3312 | 101.25 | 0.19  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3313 | 100.03 | 0.16  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3314 | 98.46  | 0.17  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3315 | 97.2   | 0.13  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3316 | 95.99  | 0.1   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3317 | 94.61  | 0.08  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3318 | 93.26  | 0.07  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3319 | 92.02  | 0.1   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3320 | 90.4   | 0.12  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3321 | 88.97  | 0.11  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3322 | 87.19  | 0.11  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3323 | 85.39  | 0.1   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3324 | 83.79  | 0.1   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3325 | 82.03  | 0.1   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3326 | 80.37  | 0.11  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3327 | 78.84  | 0.11  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3328 | 77.49  | 0.08  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3329 | 76.01  | 0.03  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3330 | 74.99  | 0.0   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3331 | 73.8   | 0.0   | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3332 | 72.09  | -0.01 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3333 | 70.38  | -0.03 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3334 | 68.65  | -0.04 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3335 | 66.94  | -0.07 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3336 | 65.54  | -0.1  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3337 | 63.83  | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3338 | 62.55  | -0.16 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3339 | 60.71  | -0.17 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3340 | 59.06  | -0.21 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3341 | 57.49  | -0.21 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3342 | 55.64  | -0.19 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3343 | 54.02  | -0.14 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3344 | 52.63  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3345 | 51.23  | -0.09 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3346 | 49.55  | -0.09 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3347 | 48.19  | -0.09 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3348 | 46.6   | -0.1  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3349 | 45.22  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3350 | 43.56  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3351 | 42.23  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3352 | 40.54  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3353 | 39.04  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3354 | 37.39  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3355 | 35.68  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3356 | 34.13  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3357 | 32.62  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3358 | 31.19  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3359 | 29.74  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3360 | 28.31  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3361 | 27.14  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3362 | 25.67  | -0.11 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3363 | 24.35  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3364 | 23.06  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3365 | 21.53  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3366 | 20.14  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3367 | 18.47  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3368 | 17.01  | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3369 | 15.25  | -0.12 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3370 | 13.9   | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3371 | 12.17  | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3372 | 10.76  | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3373 | 9.32   | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3374 | 8.03   | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3375 | 6.59   | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3376 | 5.2    | 13.0  | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3377 | 3.83   | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3378 | 2.14   | -0.13 | 4           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3379 | -0.02  | -0.08 | 5           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3380 | 1.01   | -0.08 | 5           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3381 | 2.0    | 7.0   | 5           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3382 | 2.97   | -0.05 | 5           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3383 | 4.03   | -0.01 | 5           |
+------+--------+-------+-------------+
.
.
.
```

Comment: can we do it using for loop...if yes then how

Comment: This gives you all sections in a single query and each row is numerated with its section number